Give arrow package's write_parquet does not support append is there any alternative?
I have to generate a parquet file by writing parts of the data at a time give memory constraints. The arrow package's write_parquet does not support this functionality. I understand that I can write to multiple parquet files and re-read them as a "dataset". Wondering if there are alternative packages / solutions to generate a single parquet file. Downstream users demand this. Python supports the append, but it messes up substantially with the date fields and floating point columns, and is not an option.

Re: "Python supports the append", is there an existing issue for the behavior you're seeing on the Arrow issue tracker (https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues)? If there's really an issue, it would probably be good to fix it.

Here's a related question on the Posit forum: https://forum.posit.co/t/appending-to-parquet-file-with-arrow/68383/3

I don't have a spark cluster, and on my single machine, memory is a constraint.

Do you really need to append to an existing parquet file or do you just need to create a new parquet file, write a bit, then later write a bit more, etc. and finally close it all in the same session?

I don't have enough memory to hold the entire data. I will be reading it chunk at a time, and writing it out. So, appending is necessary. I am aware there is a way to write chunks, but that won't help me as that still requires holding all data in memory to begin with.

Writing out the parquet file in chunks does not require that the data all be in RAM at once.
To demonstrate this first define gen_data(i, size) which creates a data frame with size rows consecutively starting from i in order to simulate the process discussed in the question.
Now using the peakRAM  package we check how much RAM is required to create a data frame with 1e7 rows (76.3/max 152.6 MiB).  Then generate one tenth of the data at a time and write it out to parquet as a chunk in which case we only use 0.0/max 26.7 MiB.  This shows that we did not need to have the entire data frame in RAM at once.
Below we have modified the source of write_parquet in the arrow package to write out the data in chunks.
library(arrow)
library(peakRAM)

invisible(gc())

gen_data <- function(i, size) {
  data.frame(x = as.numeric(seq(i, length = size)))
}

f <- function() {
  # define inputs
  path <- "test.parquet"

  # open
  schema <- arrow_table(gen_data(1, 1))$schema # gen 1 row to get schema
  sink <- FileOutputStream$create(path) 
  writer <- ParquetFileWriter$create(schema = schema, sink = sink,
    properties = ParquetWriterProperties$create(names(schema)))

  # writes
  for(i in seq(1, 1e7, 1e6)) { 
    dat <- gen_data(i, 1e6)
    writer$WriteTable(arrow_table(dat), chunk_size = 1e6)
    gc()
  }

  # close
  writer$Close()
  sink$close()

}

Now test it out:
if (file.exists("test.parquet")) unlink("test.parquet")
invisible(gc())
peakRAM(gen_data(1, 1e7), f())
##       Function_Call Elapsed_Time_sec Total_RAM_Used_MiB Peak_RAM_Used_MiB
## 1 gen_data(1,1e+07)             0.37               76.3             152.6
## 2               f()             1.78                0.0              26.7

